# Collapse Panel Using Header and Header Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a collapsible panel working currently using the following HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-entity panel-default>
    <div class="panel-heading" onclick="{ $(event.target).siblings('.panel-body').slideToggle('slow'); }">
       <span class="panel-heading-text">@Model.RoleName</span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="entity">
                @*A bunch of form groups*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this only allows the user to click on the panel header to collapse the panel, meaning that when they click on the text within the header, it will not collapse the panel.
Is there another approach I can take to allow the user to click anywhere within the header, including the text, to collapse the panel?

Comment: Where's your .panel-body element in the markup? It would help if you provided a fully working minimal example!

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Edited for completeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any potential future readers, the way I solved this problem was by adding `style="pointer-events: none;"` to the span where the header text was stored.

If you are using a span element to add a class to the text within a collapsible panel header, this is the correct way to make the text click-through.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-entity panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" onclick="{ $(event.target).siblings('.panel-body').slideToggle('slow'); }">
      <span class="panel-heading-text" style="pointer-events: none;">@Model.RoleName</span>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
         <div class="entity">
            @*A bunch of form groups*@
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: This solution will not work with Internet Explorer, as `pointer-events` is not supported there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `<span class="panel-heading-text">` tag. Since that tag is there, when you click on the text, you are actually clicking on that element and not the `.panel-heading` element.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-entity panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" onclick="{ $(event.target).siblings('.panel-body').slideToggle('slow'); }">
       @Model.RoleName
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="entity">
                @*A bunch of form groups*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix it for me, although I see it working in the snippet of your code. Perhaps there is a script in another file that is causing this issue.

Comment: I would check your console for errors, as I can replicate the issue you are having when you include the span. Also, in your code in the question, you are missing the closing quotes on the first div. I would still mark this answer as accepted, since it does actually address the issue.